# C++ problem adding elements to a std::list

Tags: c++, list

I'm working on a project in which I have to assign missions to timetables. Timetables are divided in three classes : **Semaine**, **Journee** and **Mission**.Each class contains a list of elements of the lower level. Here's the definition of each class :

```
class Mission{}

class Journee{
    list<Mission> missions;
    bool addMission(Mission& m);
}

class Semaine{
    list<Journee> jours;
    bool addMission(Mission& m);
}
```

I want to add a Mission to an element of the list **jours** using **Semaine::addMission()**. However, when I try doing so, the added element doesn't appear, whereas it appears when I use **Journee::addMission()**. Here's the code of each **addMission()** function:

```
bool Semaine::addMission(Mission& m){
    if(!isInWeek(m.date)) return false;
    for(Journee j : jours){
        if(j.addMission(m)){
            initMemory(); // not important here
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
bool Journee::addMission(Mission& m){
    if(m.date==date){
        missions.push_back(m);
        missions.sort();
        initMemory(); // same
        return true;   
    }
    return false;
}
// Alternative tries : change return types to Journee/Semaine and Journee&/Semaine&
```

Each call to these functions from the main file:

```
Semaine s = Semaine();
for(Mission m : missions) s.addMission(m);
cout << s; // Printed as if no mission was added

Semaine j = Journee();
for(Mission m : missions) j.addMission(m);
cout << j; // Printed with added missions
```

I understood that this kind of problem can occur when copy constructors are missing or bad, so I implemented one for each class, here they are (attributes of standard types copied with = operator):

```
Mission(const Mission& m){}
Semaine::Semaine(const Semaine& s){jours = list<Journee>(s.jours);}
Journee::Journee(const Journee& j){missions = list<Mission>(j.missions);}
//Alternative tries : std::copy, list::insert
```

Constructors used :

```
Journee::Journee(){missions = list<Mission>();}
Semaine::Semaine(){Semaine(1);}
Semaine::Semaine(int dateLundi){
    this->dateLundi = dateLundi;
    jours = list<Journee>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        jours.push_back(Journee(dateLundi+i));
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea why is it not working/how to fix it?

Comment: I can't see where you add instances of `Journee` in your `Semaine` object first

Comment: I do in the default constructors, I'm adding both

Comment: The line `Semaine::Semaine(){Semaine(1);}` doesn't do anything useful: it merely creates a temporary instance of `Semaine` and discards it immediately.

Comment: The `addMission()` methods return a value, but you never check it. Check the result an I bet that the case where nothing is added returns `false`. A debugger is always your friend ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in

```
    for(Journee j : jours){
```

This gives you a *copy* of `Journee`.

Using a reference instead, i.e.

```
    for(Journee& j : jours){
```

should solve the problem

Similarly for

```
for(Mission m : missions) s.addMission(m);
```

That should rather be:

```
for(Mission& m : missions) s.addMission(m);
```

or even better:

```
for(auto& m : missions) s.addMission(m);
```

Comment: in a for loop I'd use const &

Comment: @Eriss69 agree, but that requires that the usages of that object are `const` too. That is not the case: the parameter to `addMission()` is not `const`. So, feeding it with something `const` will not work.